# multiple programs acessing the same mySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql

I have 4 different raspberry pi's running the same program on each, the program sends information to a mySQL DB to be inserted into a table.

It is possible for this to happen or what problems will occur?

e.g.

```
Rpi:1 accessed -> sends info to DB
Rpi:2 accessed -> sends info to DB
Rpi:3 accessed -> sends info to DB
```

can these happen simultaneously?

I dont have 4 devices at the minute thats why i haven't tried it but i'm just wondering how this would work or if it is possible.

Revised : Cheers for the responses guys, each of the RPi are connected to a RFID module so when the fob get read, it send the timestamp to a DB and thats the same with all the 4 devices! Each device will be used at a random time when some one wants to access the system, will this cause problems?

Thanks :)

Comment: Well, one of the points in modern databases is to allow concurrent operations. But you should know what you are doing.

Comment: of course it is, unless the programs wont duplicate any primary keys or unique fields while inserting data to `db` everything should be fine.

Comment: If you tell us what kind of data the devices are sending (and what the target table looks like), you might get more useful answers that consider possible concurrency issues that might concern your software.

Comment: Just get familar with `Transactions`, then you have no problem :-)

Comment: @dognose Transactions won't solve all problems. If two devices read the same record and then device 1 writes some changes back and then device 2 writes different changes back, device 1's changes will be overwritten. Some kind of versioning is required.

Comment: @Jaydee absolute right - Transactions just solve the "technical" concurrency part, not the "logical".

Answer (score 0):

As @mastah indicates it really depends on what you want to do.

The answer is yes it can be done, but the some things are more complex than others. EG you want the devices to record temperature in different places, then each device will simply create a new record every few minutes along with the location name. the name and time of the record would be the unique key. No problem.

If, say, you want to be able to change any record in the database on any device, you need to think about how two people changing the same record will be reconciled.

It also depends on what you mean by "simultaneously". In general, database writes are done sequentially in "transactions". So you may need to consider whether "simultaneously" means "very quickly one after another" or not. Does the order of the writes matter?

Comment: also it might be simpler if the devices would use seperate tables (but gathering data like temperature would make a bit of a mess in db) - sorry for bad english